# Bcrypt and password hashing disabled

Tags: laravel, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I'm working with a Laravel 5.3 project and I think the developer prior to me has disabled bcrypt and Hash::make.

If I use the bcrypt function in the default RegisterController that comes with 5.3's auth system, or Hash::make, the password is stored into the DB in plain text.

Does anybody know how he could have done this and how I can enable it again?

```
/**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create($data, [
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
        ]);
    }
```

**^^ Stored in plain text**

Comment: Can you check if `Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher.php` exists in your code base? `bcrypt() ` function just uses [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a password hash. I don't think there is way to disable it.

Comment: Hey Amit, BcryptHasher.php does exist. I deleted all the vendor files and ran a composer update already. Anything else you can recommend?

Comment: Can you check if [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is working?